# how to hover the whole element no matter what

Tags: html, css, background, hover

I have this structure HTML:

```
<span class='something'>
  <a href="" title="description">
    <img src="/assets/no-image.png" alt="description" title="description" />
    <div class="info">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="subtitle">subtitle</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</span>
```

And this CSS:

```
.something {
  display: block;
  div.info {
    display: none;
  }
  a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
    img:hover {
      filter: alpha(opacity = 30);
      opacity: .30;         
    }
    div.title, div.subtitle {
      display: block;
    }
    div.info {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: -145px;
    }
  }
}
```

When I move cursor over the `<span class="something">` element, the whole area will be overlayed by green color. That's good.
The problem is, that when I move cursor over the `DIV` elements inside the `<span class="something">` (which means over `<div class="title">` and `<div class="subtitle">`), the green background disappear.

I am striving to keep there the green background even if the cursor is on those 2 DIVs.

How to do that with using CSS? Or do I need to used Javascript?

Comment: `<a>` can't have a `<div>` as a child.

Comment: @j08691 in HTML5 yes: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: True, but that doesn't solve the problem of a `div` inside of a `span `, which is still invalid.

Comment: I converted your LESS to CSS and modified it a little bit to be able to move from .something to .info without leaving the div, and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/K4ZeD/

Comment: @Aljullu - hmmm, not according to the W3's validator.

Comment: @j08691 Try this code in the validator `<a><div></div></a>`. If you set your DOCTYPE to HTML5 you don't get any error regarding to the `div` inside the `a`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your html is semantically invalid. 
You cannot have block elements inside inline elements.

Change span to div

// css

```
.something {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.something:hover {
  background: green;
}
.something:hover .info {
  display: block;
}
.something:hover .title {
  display: block;
}
.something:hover .subtitle {
  display: block;
}
.something .info {
  display: none;
}
.something .title {
  display: none;
}
.something .subtitle {
  display: none;
}
.something img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

markup

```
<div class="something">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="../styles/images/Desert.jpg" />
        </a>

        <div class="info">
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="subtitle">Subtitle</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i didn't notice it. anyways the div inside a won't work. block elements overflows. And there is something called semantics. span is intended to contain only inline elements. That is why there are two anonymous elements span and div. HTML specification clearly classifies them.